# What’s the best way of tagging bits of text for future manipulations (e.g. changing their position, their content, etc)?

Tags: microsoft-word, tags

Let’s say I am trying to design a personal foreign language dictionary file.

The initial format of the entries is like this:

• [1] [2] [3];

[4]

• [1] [2] [3];

[4]

• etc

Where, 
[1] — foreign word; [2] — part of speech; [3] — translation; [4] — example/quote sentence.

What is the best way of marking [1]–[4] as belonging to specific “categories” so that when later on there will be a need, for example, to swap [2] with [3] or add brackets to all the [2]’s, it will be an easy task to make the Word program find the needed parts and apply the required changes?

In case of [Character Styles](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Style-basics-in-Word-d382f84d-5c38-4444-98a5-9cbb6ede1ba4#bm2a) both sample tasks seem to be impossible to do without using VB macros.

Another subpar solution would be adding invisible (maybe font size 1) “letter-tags” around each text chunk of the certain category, but that would make adding words in the future rather difficult and tiresome because you’d have to add these letter-tags to each of them as well.

I’ve encountered this problem several times before too, so making the dictionary file is in itself in not the point — simply an example.

Comment: @lmfego, I think Excel would be a better fit for this problem.